# How to solve this partial derivative exercise?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

#1
The exercises says: Plug in the variables $x=3u+2v$, $y=u+5v$ in $$A(x,y)=y\frac{dz}{dx}+xy\frac{dz}{dy}$$
I don't know where to start because the chain of rule can't be used.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? You don't really need a chain rule, just differentiate $z$ after $x$ to calculate $\frac{dz}{dx}$. I Edited your formula so that it is more readable.

Comment: There is no $z$ in your formula, how should one differentiate that??

Comment: My prof is kinda crazy, he gave me this one on my last test so I was really confused, actually, I think that A(x,y)=z, just because he is crazy, but I don't know how to differentiate that, if u have any idea can u please give me the solution.

Comment: I just asked him and he replied z=z(x,y) I don't know if that usefull.

Comment: It says "plug in the variables". Okay what should be done after plugging in the variables? Should $A'$ should be calculated or should the term be rephrased in terms of the variables $u$ and $v$?

Comment: He gave me this example and told me to solve the problem like here.
https://ibb.co/18WkqZy